# Why does `crontab -` remove crontab, and can it be cancelled?

Tags: bash, cron

I hurried and forgot the *e* in `crontab -e` before I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A prompt appeared, so I closed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, same as I usually exit input prompts.

Now, without warning, my entire crontab is empty.

Why? What logic caused this to happen?
How should I close prompts other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> so that nothing is saved?

Comment: What did the prompt say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Control+C</kbd> will in this case abort `crontab` and not wipe out the current crontab entries. Otherwise, the bare `-` is a common indication on Unix that input should be read from standard input, and <kbd>Control+D</kbd> closes standard input, resulting in the empty crontab file, as nothing was piped in on standard input.

A user crontab entry along the lines of

```
@daily crontab -l > $HOME/.cron.`hostname`
```

may help against any such future oopsies by providing a backup copy of the crontab data (or you can go wild with version control, or however complex you want the backup to be).

Answer (score 14):

You replaced your crontab with contents from stdin, which was empty. It is essentially same as `crontab < /dev/null`.

Pressing Ctrl+C might be a better habit.

Your crontab is most likely gone. Backup could be somewhere in `/var/spool/cron`, but I don't know any cron daemon that maintains backups. You should set up backups of `/var/spool/cron` if it's important for you.